# Adobe Phonegap Icons, no config.xml file

Tags: javascript, ios, phonegap-build

I've been using Adobe Phonegap's Build Website to package my iOS application, however my app icon appears to be stuck on the default icon given by PhoneGap which looks like this:

[image]

I looked online for an answer and I came across this:
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html

Based on my findings, I have two questions:

1) Would I need to create a separate app icon for each device or would a single image and a defined width and height in my code suffice?

2) Do I add the following lines directly to my index.html file without anything else? The reason I am asking is because of the `<icon src=" ">` and `gap:platform="ios"` bit. Does the build created with Adobe Phonegap automatically allow me to do this or do I need to create a config.xml file and add those lines to that?

```
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
<icon src="icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild a fresh app.

Make an icon of size 1024 x 1024.

Go to this link https://makeappicon.com/

Using this link you will be able to create all required icons for both iOS and Android.

Now go to your App folder.

App folder > platforms > ios > app name > Resources > icons.

replace all the icons with your new icons.

You can do the same for Splashscreen. It requires 2048 x 2048 image size.

Comment: I don't think I currently have an App Folder. The Adobe Phonegap Build only generates a .ipa file. Would I need to open that in XCode and make the changes there?

Comment: When you create an app it automatically creates a folder. The folder is where your code is.